How to Properly Configure Nested Scroll with SliverOverlapAbsorber in Flutter
I’m building a profile screen in Flutter using a NestedScrollView. I already have a SliverOverlapAbsorber for my SliverAppBar, but I need to add another one for my TabBar. Due to dynamic content with varying heights in the middle, I can’t use the SliverOverlapAbsorber as a bottom widget. How can I properly configure my profile widget to handle this situation?
Here is my current setup:
•   NestedScrollView with SliverAppBar.
•   SliverOverlapAbsorber for the SliverAppBar.
•   Dynamic content in the middle section.
•   Need to add SliverOverlapAbsorber for TabBar without affecting the existing setup.

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
My full code:

class SimpleProfile extends StatefulWidget {
 const SimpleProfile({
   super.key,
 });

 @override
 _SimpleProfileState createState() => _SimpleProfileState();
}

class _SimpleProfileState extends State<SimpleProfile> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
 late ScrollController _scrollController;
 late TabController _tabController;

 @override
 void initState() {
   _scrollController = ScrollController();
   super.initState();
   _tabController = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   _scrollController.dispose();
   _tabController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DefaultTabController(
     length: _tabController.length,
     child: Scaffold(
       body: NestedScrollView(
         headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
           return [
             _profileAppBar(innerBoxIsScrolled),
             _profileMainInfo(),
             _tabBarSelector(),
           ];
         },
         body: Builder(
           builder: (context) => _tabBarView(),
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 Widget _profileAppBar(bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
   return SliverAppBar(
     floating: false,
     pinned: true,
     stretch: true,
     forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
     surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
     expandedHeight: 300,
     backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
     title: null,
     flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
       collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
       background: Column(
         children: [
           Expanded(
             child: LayoutBuilder(
               builder: (context, constraints) {
                 final bgHeight = constraints.maxHeight * 0.85;
                 const avatarSize = 104.0;
                 const borderWidth = 2;
                 final radius = avatarSize / 2;
                 final imgSize = (radius - borderWidth) * 2;
                 return Stack(
                   children: [
                     Positioned(
                       top: 0,
                       left: 0,
                       right: 0,
                       child: SizedBox(
                         height: bgHeight,
                         child: Container(
                           color: Colors.blue,
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                     Positioned(
                       left: 0,
                       right: 0,
                       bottom: 0,
                       child: Container(
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           shape: BoxShape.circle,
                           boxShadow: [
                             BoxShadow(
                               color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                               spreadRadius: 2,
                               blurRadius: 8,
                               offset: const Offset(0, 4),
                             ),
                           ],
                         ),
                         child: CircleAvatar(
                           radius: radius,
                           backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                           child: ClipOval(
                             child: Container(
                               color: Colors.blueAccent,
                               width: imgSize,
                               height: imgSize,
                             ),
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 );
               },
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(
             height: 20,
           ),
           Padding(
             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
             child: Text(
               'First and Last Names',
               textAlign: TextAlign.center,
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
             ),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 Widget _profileMainInfo() {
   return SliverToBoxAdapter(
     child: Container(
       color: Colors.white,
       child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
         children: [
           //some horizontal list
           Container(color: Colors.amber, height: 35),
           const SizedBox(
             height: 20,
           ),
           Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
             child: //some static height Container
                 Container(color: Colors.green, height: 75),
           ),
           if (true) ...[
             const SizedBox(
               height: 20,
             ),
             const Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
               child: Text(
                 'Some short/medium long text',
                 textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                 style: TextStyle(
                   fontSize: 17,
                   fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                   height: 22 / 17,
                   letterSpacing: -0.408,
                   textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ],
           const SizedBox(
             height: 20,
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 Widget _tabBarSelector() {
   return SliverPersistentHeader(
     pinned: true,
     delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
       TabBar(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
         controller: _tabController,
         tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
         isScrollable: true,
         labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
         labelColor: Colors.black,
         indicatorColor: Colors.black,
         unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
         tabs: const [
           Tab(text: 'tab 1'),
           Tab(text: 'tab 2'),
           Tab(text: 'tab 3'),
           Tab(text: 'tab 4'),
           Tab(text: 'tab 5'),
           Tab(text: 'tab 6'),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }

 Widget _tabBarView() {
   return TabBarView(
     controller: _tabController,
     children: List.generate(6, (index) {
       return Builder(
         builder: (BuildContext context) {
           return CustomScrollView(
             key: PageStorageKey<String>('SomeWidget$index'),
             slivers: <Widget>[
               SliverPadding(
                 padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                 sliver: SliverFixedExtentList(
                   itemExtent: 48.0,
                   delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                     (BuildContext context, int index) {
                       return ListTile(
                         title: Text('Item $index'),
                       );
                     },
                     childCount: 30,
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           );
         },
       );
     }),
   );
 }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
 _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

 final TabBar _tabBar;

 @override
 double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height + 1;
 @override
 double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height + 1;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
   return Column(
     children: [
       Container(
         color: Colors.white,
         child: _tabBar,
       ),
       Divider(
         height: 1,
         color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
         thickness: 1,
       ),
     ],
   );
 }

 @override
 bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
   return false;
 }
}

Whenever I change tabs, the inner scroll content starts from the top of the screen under the app bar. I need to add an inset to maintain the scroll position.
enter image description here


wrap SliverAppBar with SliverOverlapAbsorber
SliverOverlapAbsorber(
  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
  sliver: SliverAppBar(
    
  ),
);

and for each tab add SliverOverlapInjector
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    // add this line
    SliverOverlapInjector(handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context)),
    SliverPadding(
      padding: padding,
      sliver: sliver,
    ),
  ],
),


It is not working, I have _profileMainInfo() in the middle, somehow I need to add _tabBarSelector() to Absorber. And in this case SliverOverlapInjector add extra space in the beginning

first, I want to point out that you don't need to create a _tabController because you are using DefaultTabController, so it can save you from few lines of code.

second, I think that I didn't understood your problem, if you just need to save the innerscroll position in each tab, all you need to do is to add a PageStorageKey to each

I have PageStorageKey, the problem is that items start from the top, not from the tabbar
